# Using accelerometer values in python with kivy crashes app

Tags: python, android, numpy, kivy

I'm having some trouble making use of accelerometer values inside a kivy android app.
I can read the accelerometer values correctly and they are displayed in a meaningful way in my app; I can print them to a textlabel.

However, as soon as I try to use them in a mathematical operation (say a subtraction, marked with a comment in the code), the app crashes giving the following error:

```
Unsupported operand type(s) for -: ‘NoneType’ and ‘NoneType’
```

The code is as follows:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock 
from plyer import accelerometer
from plyer import gravity
import numpy as np

class TestApp(App):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__()
        self.sensorEnabled= False
        self.acc= np.array([0, 0, 0])
        self.grav= np.array([0, 0, 0])
        self.lineal= np.array([0, 0, 0])

    def leer_accel(self, dt):
        self.acc= np.asarray(accelerometer.acceleration)
        self.grav= np.asarray(gravity.gravity)
        test= self.acc[0]- self.grav[0] #THIS LINE CRASHES THE APP!!
        self.root.ids['a_x'].text= f"{str(self.acc)}"
        self.root.ids['a_y'].text= f"{str(type(self.acc))}"
        self.root.ids['a_z'].text= " "
        #self.root.ids['g_x'].text= " "
        #self.root.ids['g_y'].text= " "
        self.root.ids['g_z'].text=f"{self.acc- self.grav}"
    def empezar(self):
        try: 
            if not self.sensorEnabled:
                accelerometer.enable()
                gravity.enable()
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.leer_accel, 1/100)
                self.sensorEnabled= True
                self.root.ids['boton_1'].text= "Parar"
            else: 
                accelerometer.disable()
                Clock.unschedule(self.leer_accel)
                self.sensorEnabled= False
                self.root.ids.boton_1.text= "Empezar"
        except NotImplementedError:
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()
            self.root.ids.status.text= "Accelerometro no soportado"

App= TestApp()
App.run()
```

There's something (obvious) I'm sure I'm missing since the variables exist and I can access them to print them out, however I haven't caught the error yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you probably get values of None at some point, perhaps when the accelerometer is first accessed. If you print every value along the way, you'll probably see that in the log.

The fix then would be to check for this in `leer_accel` and just return early if the data isn't good.

Comment: You were right, it seems the accelerometer values aren't available instantly; once the accelerometer is enabled with `accelerometer.enable()` , it will return tuples filled with `None` for 30 or 40 miliseconds at most, I solved the problem by adding `time.sleep(0.05)` in the function `empezar(self)`